# Open Editor on Specific Tab Position in Custom Plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin

In my Custom Plugin I would like to open one specific Editor always in the first Tab Position. Is there a way to tell on Editor-Open Action where to Open the Editor concerning the tab-position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to specify the tab position for the editor when you open it.

Comment: Tankts for the quick response.